# Subdomain to Port redirect

Tags: apache, redirect, amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain

I created a AWS instance to hold my jenkins and archiva services 5 days ago.
I already have my own domain, and created DNS Subdomain `jenkins.mydomain.com` and `archiva.mydomain.com` entries to redirect to my AWS instance.

But, I wanna use something like that:
`jenkins.mydomain.com` instead of `jenkins.mydomain.com:8080`
`archiva.mydomain.com` instead of `archiva.mydomain.com:8081`

Someone can help me?

I already instaled a apache2 service too.

Editing... to make more clear because i don't figure out anything...

I have my own domain: `mydomain.com`
I created a CNAME entry `dev.mydomain.com` on DNS server that point to `somename.no-ip.info`
I created a AWS instance and installed no-ip update client. So I have sure that `somename.no-ip.info` is pointing to this machine

On this machine I have 2 services: Jenkins on port `9090` and Archiva on port `9091`.

I'm able to access these using `somename.no-ip.info:9090` and `somename.no-ip.info:9091`

I'm also able to access it from `dev.mydomain.com:9090` and `dev.mydomain.com:9091`

What I want, if it's possible, is access from `jenkins.mydomain.com` and `archiva.mydomain.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now.

I make CNAME entries for `jenkins.mydomain.com` and `archiva.mydomain.com` both pointing to `somename.no-ip.info`.

On my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf i setted:

```
NameVirtualHost jenkins.mydomain.com:80 
<VirtualHost jenkins.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com.br
    ServerName jenkins.mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9090/ 
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost archiva.mydomain.comr:80 
<VirtualHost archiva.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerName archiva.mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9091/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9091/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

But now I'm getting this warning:
`[warn] NameVirtualHost archiva.mydomain.com:80 has no VirtualHosts`

Someone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

adding a reverse proxy in apache will fix this problem , something along the lines of wiki.apache.org/httpd/TomcatReverseProxy

Answer (score 0):

This reply is late and I'm sure you have figured it out by now.  I see your NameVirtualHost with an 'r' tagged at the end of your .com, which I am sure is a typo and thus creating your problem.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

you also need to create a virtual host to let appache point to the correct folder when request is made on port 9091

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.