# AWS Apache2 reverse proxy with godaddy not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache2, reverse-proxy

I have purchased a godaddy domain and AWS EC2 instance with elastic ip. In godaddy I created following entries

A-name entry ( mydomain.com ) pointing to elastic ip
And a C-name entry (app2.mydomain.com) pointing to same elastic ip

Inside amazon EC2 instance , I am running two applications
app1 - running on localhost:3000
app2 - running on localhost:4000

Now, I am trying to achieve below 
mydomain.com should point to app1 running on localhost:3000
app2.mydomain.com should point to app2 running on localhost:4000

I have installed apache2 on EC2 and followed below links to configure reverse proxy
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879819/subdomain-to-port-redirect)

I created myproxy.conf under apache2/sites-available as below

```
<VirtualHost mydomain.com:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost app2.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerName app2.mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4000/
</VirtualHost>
```

But I can't get it working. But when I change the conf as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app2.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Both mydoamin.com and app2.mydomain.com launch same app2 application.

I could not figure out what I am missing.

**Edit**

Soon after I post this, I tried something which seems to work. I added *.80 instead of app2.mydomain.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app2.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4000/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are trying to run code on apache2 default port 80.
You need to run both application on diff port.Try running code on different port

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
Listen 8081
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to open port in listen mode by LISTEN port_no